# Redirect to url of Programatically created Product

Tags: magento-1.9, product, module, url, controllers

once we click on **button** in product view page, we are creating **New Product Programatically** & displaying pop up with message : "`new product created`"  Instead of displaying **pop up** , i need to redirect to Newly created Product's url.

```
public function createSimpleProductAndRedirectAction()
    {       
        $originalProductId = $this->getRequest()->getParam("id");           
        $originalProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())->load($originalProductId);

        $_productUrl = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product->getId())->getUrlKey();         

        if ($product = $this->_createProduct(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type::TYPE_SIMPLE, true, $originalProduct, $newImagePath)) 
        {                   
            if(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) 
            {
                return $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode("new Product created"));
            }       
        }               
    }

protected function _createProduct($type, $doSave = true, $originalProduct, $newImagePath = "")
    {

        try {
            if (isset($login) && (is_array($login) && !empty($login)) || ($login != "")) {
                $designId = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getData('mydesign_id');
                $session->login($login['username'], $login['password']);
                $result['redirect'] = $this->_getRefererUrl() ? $this->_getRefererUrl() : Mage::getUrl('customer/account', array(
                    '_secure' => true
                ));
                $result['success'] = true;          

                $customerId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerId();               

                $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($result));
                return $this;
            } else {
                $customerId = "";

            }

            if(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {
                $res = $this->saveProduct($type, $doSave, $originalProduct, $newImagePath);
                $result['success'] = true;
                $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($result));
                return $this; exit;
            } else {

            }

        } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {}

        } catch (Exception $e) { }              
    }

public function saveProduct($type, $doSave = true, $originalProduct, $newImagePath) {

            Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

            $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');

            $product->setName($originalProduct->getName());        
            $product->save();   

            return $product;
    }
```

I tried replacing this code :

```
return $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode("new Product created"));
```

by below code :

```
$_productUrl = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product->getId())->getUrlKey(); 
return $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($_productUrl));
```

**Error** :

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Amasty_Example_AmastyController::getId() in line 

$_productUrl = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product->getId())->getUrlKey();
```

Is i am using code in wrong place ? because `echo  $_productUrl` gave empty value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$product doesn't appear to have been defined when you called ->getId() on it. Perhaps try getting Id from $originalProduct or defer calling getUrl() until after the _createProduct method has been called?

Comment: yes , when i try with `return $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($originalProduct));` it will display Product details in pop up , but i need to redirect to `newly created product`

Comment: Ahh ok, you want to actually be redirected to that page.  Sorry for misunderstanding.

Comment: thats fine..... you are right, instead of displaying , i want to redirect.....

Comment: Perhaps you should explain a little more in the post - is what you're using custom code?  If not then which class is it?

Comment: I won't be able to assist because I mainly work purely back end stuff like APIs - etc, I mean elaborate so that perhaps someone else will be able to help with it. However, the error you're getting is coming from a 3rd Party developer (Amasty) - not sure what that is about, but will be hard for people to assist without context.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion,  i will edit my question with more details.....